# How do I link images I uploaded to GCS to my React front end?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to link the files I upload to Google Cloud. I found that the link to the images I'm uploading are formatted like this:

storage.googleapis.com/bucket/image.jpeg

But the name of the image keeps getting randomized upon upload. The authorization link in the bucket on GCS looks like this:
https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket/45jwaxo0ekkmj9sk7ojqyshrtl9l
With the Object name being: 45jwaxo0ekkmj9sk7ojqyshrtl9l instead of "image.jpeg"

My front end is written in React and the form responsible for uploading it looks like this:

```
function Home(){
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', moviepic);
    formData.append('title', moviepic.name);
    fetch('/movies', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })

        console.log(formData)
      }

return(
<div id='uploadform'>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<input type="file" name="image"accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={(e) => setMoviepic(e.target.files[0])}/>
                    <input type='submit'/>
            </form> 


<img src = "I'm trying to figure this out" />

</div>
)
}
```

I want to be able to upload my image files to GCS with their original names in place so I can link them in my image tags in the front end. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[message on server console when I upload the file to gcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zhfZ.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the image name getting randomized on upload?  What does the browser debug show as the final REST request being sent to GCS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.